# Facebook application connection doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem with my logging into my Facebook application.
When I click "login" I get redirected to Facebook to accept the permissions then Facebook redirects me back. But it doesn't change anything. The `URL` down is dynamic generated. When I try the same script on an other URL that's not dynamic it's work.

Here is the URL there i try to perform a login.
http://www.testaiq.se/test_592.html

What could be the problem? `PHP` is behind the `URL` over here.

```
require_once("facebook/facebook.php");

// Creating our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'XXX',
));

// Getting User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// Get Access token
$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// We may or may not have this data based on whether the user is logged in.
//
// If we have a $user id here, it means we know the user is logged into
// Facebook, but we don't know if the access token is valid. An access
// token is invalid if the user logged out of Facebook.

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    // Retrieving user's friend list using fb graph api
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if (!$user) {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    'scope' => 'user_likes'
  ));
}
```

Comment: When you post a question on SO, we expect at least a snippet of your CODE! post it if possible!

Comment: Sorry, forget that! @AdamAzad

Is there maybe anything I have to change in the Facebook Developer App Setup?

Comment: Probably yes, because your code looks fine & should work, and that URL you posted doesn't seem to have Login button or anything Facebook apps related... can you share where's your app login page is?

Comment: Looks like somebody pay instead, haha. Here is a new one http://www.testaiq.se/test_592.html. @AdamAzad

And here is a pic on my Setup in the Facebook Developer Area.
http://cl.ly/V4Ju

Comment: that one did work, but after the callback nothing actually changed in the page, please explain what do you want and doesn't work for you so I give more information & help you :)

Comment: I have an IF like this. `<?php if ($user) {} else {} ?>` . After I have logged in i want to show a like button. But instead i see that login text. @AdamAzad

Comment: put your like button `HTML` like this `($user) { echo 'LIKE BUTTON HTML'; }` this is a basic PHP question ;)

Comment: I modified the code over here. Here is the real code.
`<?php if ($user): ?>    
         Hello!
    <?php else: ?>
      <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
    <?php endif ?>`
@AdamAzad

Comment: I find out that User returns 0 on this url [link](http://testaiq.se/test_592.html). When I try it on http://www.testaiq.se/fb_app.php it works great!

Comment: That's because you probably set your **Website URL** to `testaiq.se/fb_app.php` in your app dashboard

Comment: What would it be instead? The URL i wan't it on is dynamic generated. @AdamAzad I have tried with http://www.testaiq.se only but it doesn't work.

Comment: no it won't because your call back must match your website url that configured in app dashboard

Comment: What should i do instead?

Comment: Learn more PHP ;) use sessions http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: How would that help me if I can't sign in?